# SelectField WTForms isn't returning the selected value on form submission

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm trying to create a SelectField to change the user verification status with values (True, False), however, the field isn't changing the value returned at all keep returning the default value, below is the code for the Form.

```
class UpdateUserForm(FlaskForm):
username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired()])
email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
status = SelectField("Account Status", choices=[(True, "Verified"), (False, "Not Verified")], coerce=bool, validators=[InputRequired()])
submit = SubmitField("Update")

def validate_username(self, username):
    if username.data != g.username:
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("That username is taken, please choose a different one.")

def validate_email(self, email):
    if email.data != g.email:
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("That email is taken, please choose a different one.")
```

In the route I'm trying to fetch the user info from the database so as an admin I can edit on that but the selectField would keep setting this value as the result on Form submission, Below is the code for the route.

```
@admin.route("/admin_panel/update_user/<int:user_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@admin_login_required
def update_user(user_id):

user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()

g.username = user.username
g.email = user.email

updateUserForm = UpdateUserForm()
updateUserForm.username.data = user.username
updateUserForm.email.data = user.email
updateUserForm.status.data =  user.verified

if updateUserForm.validate_on_submit():
    user.username = updateUserForm.username.data
    user.email = updateUserForm.email.data
    user.verified = updateUserForm.status.data

    db.session.commit()
    flash("Account updated!", 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('admin.admin_panel'))

return render_template("admin/update_user.html", title="Update User", updateUserForm=updateUserForm)
```

Comment: Hi Shawky Ahmed
Welcome on Stackoverflow. In order to get started, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
It would be helpful if you provide a minimal running example of your code.